# Postgresql select two correlated rows in a table and shows the opposite of the correlated field into another new column from the output result

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table `table1` as shown below:

```
+--------+----------------+---------+
| userid | correlated_id  | type    |
+--------+----------------+---------+
| user_1 | abc-123        |husband  |
| user_2 | abc-123        |wife     |
| user_1 | def-456        |solo     |
| user_1 | ghi-789        |brother  |
| user_3 | ghi-789        |sister   |
+--------+----------------+---------+
```

I would like my select query to be filtered by `userid = 'user_1'` and `type = 'husband'` as well as create another column named `related_userid` from the query as shown below:

```
+--------+----------------+---------+----------------+
| userid | correlated_id  | type    | related_userid |
+--------+----------------+---------+----------------+
| user_1 | abc-123        | husband | user_2         |
+--------+----------------+---------+----------------+
```

I would also like the query to be as efficient as possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of self join  to get the desired result:

```
SELECT a.userid, a.correlated_id, a.type, b.userid AS related_userid
FROM   table1 a
JOIN   table1 b ON a.correlated_id = b.correlated_id
where a.userid = 'user_1' and a.type = 'husband' and a.userid <> b.userid;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can self join the table based on the `correlated_id`:

```sql
SELECT a.userid, a.correlated_id, a.type, b.userid AS related_userid
FROM   table1 a
JOIN   table1 b ON a.correlated_id = b.correlated_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_agg()` and then remove the current user:

```
select t.*,
       array_remove(array_agg(userid) over (partition by correlated_id), user_id) as other_user_ids
from t;
```

This should work even when there are more than two users that are correlated.

Comment: Would love to try this out to see the efficiency but too bad my server is using Postgresql 8.0 so array_agg can't be used here :(

Comment: @ChngFongChia . . . Postgres 8.0 passed its end of life almost a decade ago (9 years, 11 months).  You should be using supported software.